# Building a vector of multiple structure values in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, loops, structure

I'm trying to create a function that reads in a field of a structure to create a vector of fields.  I have a structure of the form:

```
subject(i).stride(j).strideLength
```

and there are 10 subjects, about 10 strides per subject.  I can create a long vector of the strideLength of all subjects, all strides with code like this:

```
k = 1;
for i=1:10
    for j=1:size(subject(i).stride, 2)       
        varVector(k) = subject(i).stride(j).strideLength;
        k = k + 1;
    end
end
```

however, there are a lot of different fields I want to do this with, and I'd like to do it with a function that I can call like this:

```
x(1) = groupData(strideLength);
```

but I can't figure out the syntax to append strideLength to subject(i).stride(j). within the above loop in a function.  This is what I hoped would work and didn't:

```
function [varVector] = groupData(var)
%groupData returns a concatenated vector of a given variable (speed, etc.) 

k = 1;
for i=1:10
    for j=1:size(subject(i).stride, 2)       
        varVector(k) = subject(i).stride(j).var;
        k = k + 1;
    end
end
end
```

Any thoughts on how to do this right?  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `groupData` function, pass in the field/variable name as a string

```
x(1) = groupData('strideLength');
```

Then in the body of the code, access this field as follows

```
varVector(k) = subject(i).stride(j).(var);
```

Try the above and see what happens!